# if condition not met when working with serial comma/array_pop

Tags: php, arrays, forms, postback

Newbie here working on a simple post back form (complex for me actually). My goal is that if only one item is selected, the word 'and' would not print. The file works nice when three or more things are selected as it drops the last comma, but if it's only the the last element then i want to drop the 'and...' so that only the last element prints.

I've trying working out an if else if else statement but i'm not getting it. 
Thanks for any help - i'm just trying to make my little experiment a little better.

```
<?php
    define('THIS_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));//shows webroot

    if(isset($_POST['submit3'])){ //proces form - catches the post info when submit clicked

    $arr = $_POST['sundae'];
    $lastElement = array_pop($arr);

    if ($arr == ""){$myReturn = "stuff"; echo $myReturn;}
    else
    {$myReturn = "<span style=\"color:red; font-weight: bold\">You have selected: " . implode(', ',$arr)." and ".$lastElement;
    $myReturn .= "</span> <br />";
    $myReturn .= '<input type="button" value="Reload page" onclick="reloadPage()" >';
    echo $myReturn;}
    }else{// show the form if no posties
        echo
        '
        <form action="myTest.php" method ="post">
            Select a size:<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="One Scoop"> One Scoop<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Two Scoops"> Two Scoops<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Three Scoops"> Three Scoops<br />

            <hr ><br />

            Select a flavor:<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Chocolate">Chocolate<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Coffee">Coffee<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Double Fudge">Double Fudge<br />

            <hr ><br />

            Select your Toppings:<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Applesauce">Applesauce<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Blueberries">Blueberries<br />


            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Bubblegum">Bubblegum<br />

            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Caramel">Caramel<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Hot Fudge">Hot Fudge<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Gummy Bears">Gummy Bears<br />

            Select a Whip:<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Double Whipped Cream">Double Whipped Cream<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Marishino Cherry">Vanilla Whipped Cream<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Whipped Cream">Whipped Cream<br />

            <hr ><br />

            Select a Cherry:<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Black Cherry">Black Cherry<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Frozen Lake Cherry">Frozen Lake Cherry<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Marishino Cherry">Marishino Cherry<br />
            <br />
            <hr ><br />

            Wopuld you like to add one "waffer-thin" mint? (No charge)<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="sundae[]" value="Wafer-Thin Mint">Yes<br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit3" >
        </form>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: may should you try replacing if ($arr == "") by if (count($arr) === 0) as $arr is an array and not a string

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying if there are only 2 elements you don't want the and?  If so:

```
else
{
  //> 1 because we already popped the last element
  if (count($arr) > 1) $lastElement = " and " . $lastElement;
  $myReturn = "<span style=\"color:red; font-weight: bold\">You have selected: " . implode(', ',$arr).$lastElement;
```